# AdMob adverts are not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

They used to work but after I reinstalled windows and then new android 5.0 with sdk 21 etc. came out and they ceased working. Do we have to do something different when coding the ads into the apps now?

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
              />
```

XML file:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxx"/>
```

Main .java:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("xxx")
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: what does logcat say? any errors?

Comment: just something like - cant get ad, or something. Same info on the linux (fresh system) and win 8.1 so its not firewall problem. So i did not see banner in the application and i dont know what to do.

Comment: Put exactly what logcat says in your question, it's very important for debugging

Comment: Which google play version do you use? Make sure it is the latest one.

Comment: im always use newest version. btw. i will give you catlog screen in some mins, emulator is extremely slow (+ sometimes i have info "lanuch canceled" but its new, clean project with just AD)

Comment: @Chin http://i.imgur.com/pOjV6TC.png

Comment: @Chin and sometimes i have info: GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE IS MISSING but im using NEW lib and im using it in properties of the project http://i.imgur.com/vpwt1dA.png

Comment: What SDK is your minSDK?